# append to array from different class in swift

Tags: swift, append, viewcontroller, controllers

Im trying to append to my array

```
var feedArray: [AnyObject] = []
```

from another class.
I have 2 classes:

```
class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,
     UICollectionViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

      var feedArray: [AnyObject] = []
```

and

```
class AddEditViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,
      UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
```

I want to in my "AddEditViewController" append the array "feedArray".
But I'm not able.
I have tried:

```
FeedViewController().feedArray.append("TheObjectImTryingToAdd")
```

I even tried to put

```
print(FeedViewController().feedArray.count)
```

but the result is always 0 even though the array have 3 objects.

what I'm i doing wrong? if you want to see detailed code, this is my previous question: [why won't my main viewcontroller update when i segue back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936962/why-wont-my-main-viewcontroller-update-when-i-segue-back/33938082#33938082)

Comment: `FeedViewController()` creates a new instance of the view controller. You have to access the view controller that is being presented instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks @adam  I was actually creating the answer when you posted, : ) thanks

Answer (score 3):

So, After playing around a little bit and trying to learn, I found the solution

First of all, add the array outside of the class so it is global, so instead of:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import MobileCoreServices

class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,
UICollectionViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
   var feedArray: [AnyObject] = []
```

change it so you have:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import MobileCoreServices

 var feedArray: [AnyObject] = []

class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,
UICollectionViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

And instead of using

```
FeedViewController().feedArray.append(feedItem)
```

Now you can use:

```
feedArray.append(feedItem)
```

What the problem was, is that every time i used : "FeedViewController().fee..." I created a new instance, so i actually didn't append the array properly.

I hope it helped.